# Laravel Nova - Labels missing in select dropdown for BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

User model with agency relationship:

```
public function agency_nurse_relationship()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Agency::class, 'agency_nurse');
}
```

User nova resource:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        BelongsToMany::make('Agency', 'agency_nurse_relationship', 'App\Nova\Agency')
    ];
}
```

Agency attach dropdown:

[image]

Update:

There was a relatable Query in User nova resource, which I commented out for testing:

```
public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    if ($request->resource() == 'App\Nova\Agency') {

        return $query->where('role', 'nurse')->doesntHave('agency_nurse_relationship');
    }

    return parent::relatableQuery($request, $query);
}
```

Comment: Check whether you have any `relatableQuery` function that filter out the agencies.

Comment: There was this related query, but I commented it and tested. Still there is this issue.

Comment: Check `relatableQuery` under `Agency` resource. or it is possible `relatableAgencies`  function under `User` resource. Assuming there are records in agencies table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `\App\Nova\Agency` Nova resource `$title` property value which will used to represent the resource when being displayed.

`public static $title = 'name';`. Instead of `name` use your column name property you want to display.

Comment: Thanks man! You save my day. I didnt thought this would be that simple issue